# I'm not able to read and write to the same file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to have the code read and repeat the last line of text in an input file, and put an underscore line right below it. As the code is, it will cout the last line to the terminal but won't output anything to the file. If I remove the while(getline()), the underscore line will appear but then it can't find the line string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string underscoreDiv (int lengthText){

    string underscores;
    
    for(int i{}; i<lengthText; i++)
    {
        underscores += "_";
    }
    
    return underscores + "\n";
}
int main(){
    
    fstream fileApp("C:\\Users\\trist\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Notes_application\\Notes_app.txt", ios::in | ios::app);
        
    if(fileApp.is_open()){
        
        string underscore;
        string line;
    
        underscore=underscoreDiv(80); 

        while(getline(fileApp, line)){} ///removing this line
        
        cout<<line;

        fileApp<<"\n"<<line<<endl;
        fileApp<<underscore<<endl;
        
        fileApp.close();
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Text file not file";
    }
        
    system("C:\\Users\\trist\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Notes_application\\Notes_app.txt");
    
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this modified code that reads the last line and prints it and then prints the underscore line but I'm having to open, close, then reopen the input file which makes it too slow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string underscoreDiv (int lengthText){

    string underscores;
    
    for(int i{}; i<lengthText; i++)
    {
        underscores += "_";
    }
    
    return underscores + "\n";
}
int main(){
    
    fstream fileApp("C:\\Users\\trist\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Notes_application\\Notes_app.txt", ios::app | ios::in);
        string underscore;
        string line;
    if(fileApp.is_open()){
        
        
    
        underscore=underscoreDiv(80);

        while(getline(fileApp, line)){}
        
        cout<<line;
        
        fileApp<<"\n"<<line<<endl;  ///these 2 lines don't do anything
        fileApp<<underscore<<endl;
        
        fileApp.close();
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Text file not file";
    }

    fileApp.open("C:\\Users\\trist\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Notes_application\\Notes_app.txt", ios::app | ios::in);

        fileApp<<"\n"<<line<<endl;
        fileApp<<underscore<<endl;
        
    ///system("C:\\Users\\trist\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Notes_application\\Notes_app.txt"); ///too lazy to write a close statement here.
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So don't close the file after your read; you've already opened it for appending. what's the issue?

Comment: You cannot use `std::ios::app` and `std::ios::in` together. As a general rule, you should also avoid re-using file streams. Just create one as necessary: `std::ifstream` to read the file, and `std::ofstream` to write the file. Also, be watchful of your loop parentheses.

Comment: @Dúthomhas there is a reason that `std::ftsream` exists, is there not?

Comment: Of course there is, but you have to admit it's harder to read and write the same file, and often outside the ability of a beginner.

Comment: @Slava “A suboptimal solution exists (especially for beginners) therefore we should use it over solutions more specific to our needs”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you encounter has to do with the *state* of the stream. After each IO operation the result of that operation is stored in internhal state bits of the stream.

There is a very good overview in the CPP reference [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate). Please especially look at the table at the bottom of this page.

After the execution of the loop `while(getline(fileApp, line)){}` the eof bit of the stream is set. And only because of that, the while loop stops. Look in the table. If the eof bit is set, the `bool` function will return `false`. And since the `while`-loop excpects a `boolean` value, the bool function of the stream (that will be returned by `std::getline`) will be called.

So, now that we reached the end of the file, the stream is in `fail` state.

And then, no further IO operation on this stream will be executed.

Solution: Call the streams `clear` function after your while loop: `fileApp.clear();`

Recommendation: In general you should always check the state of a stream after IO operations.